# Use Hash of Arrays of Hashes as Counter

Tags: perl

Trying to parse an array with common elements to create a new hash that contains count information.  The structure I'm trying to create is like this:

```
{
    var1 => [
        cat1 => 50,
        cat2 => 3,
        cat3 => 5
    ],
    var2 => [
       cat2 => 12,
       cat4 => 4,
       cat5 => 1
    ]
}
```

I know how to make the hash of arrays, but I can't quite figure out how to have the internal array represent a hash of counts as above.  The data structure I have is an array of arrays, with many more elements.  But, as a toy example, here is what I'm trying to work with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Data::Dump;

my @array = (
    ["cat1", "var1"],
    ["cat2", "var1"],
    ["cat2", "var1"],
    ["cat2", "var2"],
    ["cat1", "var1"],
    ["cat1", "var1"],
);

my %counts;
for my $elem (@array) {
    push(@{$counts{$elem->[1]}}, $elem->[0]);
}
dd \%counts;
```

I can't figure out how to modify that `push()` call to push an anonymous array with counts derived from looping through `@array` (bad name, I know..just for demo purposes).

I guess I can do this in two steps.  But, it seems like there should be a simple way to count the elements when I'm loading them into `%counts`.  Can someone show me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to count here. Where's your input data that you're counting?

Comment: I'm trying to count the number of cats per var essentially.  Var will be unique, which is why I want to make it a hash key, but cats can be common to each var.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You don't push, you increment.

Comment: *"I can't quite figure out how to have the internal array represent a hash of counts as above"* What you have shown is a hash of arrays. Although you have used the fat comma as if it were within a hash, you actually have an array: `[ 'cat1', 50, 'cat2', 3, 'cat3', 5 ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected data structure is flawed. You need a hash reference on the second level.

```
{
    var1 => [       # {
        cat1 => 50,
        cat2 => 3,
        cat3 => 5
    ],              # }
    var2 => [       # {
       cat2 => 12,
       cat4 => 4,
       cat5 => 1
    ]               # }
}
```

With an array you cannot have key/value pairs properly, and just end up with an ordered list.

Once you use a hash, you can simply use the var as the first key and count the cats within. There's no need to `push` anything anywhere. Perl's [*autovivification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) will take care of creating everything for you.

```
my %counts;
foreach my $elem (@array) {
    #        var             cat 
    $counts{ $elem->[1] }->{ $elem->[0] }++;
}
```

Output:

```
{
    var1   {
        cat1   3,
        cat2   2
    },
    var2   {
        cat2   1
    }
}
```

Take a look at [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more information.

Comment: Ahhh!  I was mis-thinking the final data structure.  Of course it needs to be a hash of hashes!  Thank you very much!